# Correcting inconsistent name spellings in flex

Tags: text-processing

I am currently working on an assignment to read a BibTex file and store the data about all the categories, authors and their publications, etc...

In the BibTex file, however, many times the same names are spelled in different ways, sometimes even with unknown characters.

Here is an example of those inconsistencies:

[image: Different spelling examples]

The only way I know how to do this is to create regular expressions specific to each case, and even so I don't know if it would work for the unknown characters. However, there are way too many authors to go about doing it this way.

How could I go about automatically detecting and correcting these spelling inconsistencies to correctly save all authors and their respective publications in a flex filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a known list of good authors, for each input author, match them against the list using [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy).

If you do not have a list of known authors, you'll need to make one or get a list of names from somewhere such as Wikipedia.